# Two Vue Roots, but only one DIV

Tags: vue.js

Can you use multiple Vue instances on the same page, which operate on different parts of the DOM? Indeed you can, see e.g. https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/using-multiple-vue-instances-page. In the following code I get 2 Vue roots, but only one DIV gets rendered. The other DIV is deleted from DOM. Why that?

```
<body>
<div id="firstname">
    <input type="text" v-model="name">
    <p>{{ name }} {{ lastname() }}</p>
</div>
<div id="lastname">
    <input type="text" v-model="name">
    <p>{{ firstname() }} {{ name }}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>

  const app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#firstname',
    data: {
      name: 'Anna'
    },
    methods: {
      lastname: function(){ return app2.$data.name }
    }
  });

  const app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#lastname',
    data: {
      name: 'Müller'
    },
    methods: {
      firstname: function(){ return app1.$data.name }
    }
  });

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the second div is rendered because `app1`'s rendering fails. Why does it fail? Because it depends on `app2`, which is not initialized yet.

If you check the console you can see the error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'app2'
>   before initialization"
>
> (found in <Root>)

How to solve this? I'm not sure, I guess some kind of a shared object defined before the instances could do it.